# Kubernetes: how to properly change apiserver runtime settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, kubernetes

I'm using `kube-aws` to run a Kubernetes cluster on AWS, and everything works as expected.

Now, I realize that cron jobs aren't turned on in the version I'm using (`v1.7.10_coreos.0`), while the documentation for Kubernetes only states the following:

> For previous versions of cluster (< 1.8) you need to explicitly enable batch/v2alpha1 API by passing --runtime-config=batch/v2alpha1=true to the API server (see Turn on or off an API version for your cluster for more).

And the documentation directed to in that text only states this (it's the actual, full documentation):

> Specific API versions can be turned on or off by passing --runtime-config=api/ flag while bringing up the API server. For example: to turn off v1 API, pass --runtime-config=api/v1=false. runtime-config also supports 2 special keys: api/all and api/legacy to control all and legacy APIs respectively. For example, for turning off all API versions except v1, pass --runtime-config=api/all=false,api/v1=true. For the purposes of these flags, legacy APIs are those APIs which have been explicitly deprecated (e.g. v1beta3).

I have been unsuccessful in finding information about how to change the configuration of a running cluster, and I, of course, don't want to try to re-run the command on `api-server`.

Note that kube-aws still use `hyperkube`, and not `kubeadm`. Also, the `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`-directory only contains the `ssl`-directory.

The setting I want to apply is this: `--runtime-config=batch/v2alpha1=true`

What is the proper way, preferably using **`kubectl`**, to apply this setting and have the `apiserver`s restarted?

Thanks.

Comment: It's highly, **highly** unusually for `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` to be not only empty, but missing entirely, since in 90% of the cases, apiserver is provisioned _statically_ by `kubelet`, to get one out of the chicken-and-egg situation of requiring a working apiserver to use kubectl against. Your setup _may_ be using systemd to manage both kubelet and apiserver, so `systemctl list-units | grep -E 'kube|apiserver'` and see if anything interesting shows up. But either way, changing the apiserver's command line is the only mechanism I know of to accomplish what you are asking

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Matthew! The output of that command gives me an error: `Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1`. I'm running it on one of the `apiserver` pods. If the manifests directory is empty, would it be safe to add it? I'm mosty curious about how to update the config and then restart `apiserver`. Do I just kill the pods? Or can I run a command with `kubectl` to restart apiserver?

Comment: _I'm running it on one of the apiserver pods_ ahhh, now I see what's going on; my apologies: you will want to execute that (along with every other change to the way the apiserver runs) on the Node(s) of those apiservers (which, again, I would expect to be static); due to comment length, I'll answer the 2nd half in a separate comment

Comment: _how to update the config and then restart apiserver_ Assuming (!) the apiserver is declared by a static manifest, then when that file changes on disk (within a certain window of seconds), I would expect `kubelet` to notice that change, kill the apiserver container/Pod, and re-launch it with the new config -- just as it is programmed to do via commands from the apiserver itself. If you have multi-master, AFAIK one must also update the matching apiserver's manifests on the other Nodes, after verifying the first change did what you expected

Comment: Thanks Matthew, really appreciating your assistance! Apparently, I failed to test it with the alpha type set, which is a bit embarrassing. I really thought I did. However, the information you're providing now still is very valuable to me as I haven't found documentation on it. Where can I find that static manifest? Since it's not in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`? Note that I used `kube-aws`, which uses `hyperkube`, not `kubeadm`, for deployment.

Comment: _Where can I find that static manifest?_ the short version is wherever `kubelet` is looking for them, so I would start with `systemctl cat kubelet.service` and look for interesting directories in the unit file, and if that doesn't prove interesting, then for sure launching `kubelet` with `--v=100` will show you **everything** it is trying to do. FWIW, this very discussion is why I loathe those opaque cluster deployment tools. [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray#readme) is fantastic because it is declarative, and easy to read, and thus troubleshoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`batch/v2alpha1=true` is set by default in `kube-aws`. You can find it [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kube-aws/blob/22673054e2e2de1f096980050a5f52060974929a/core/controlplane/config/templates/cloud-config-controller#L2040)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Dang, I wonder how I missed to test that. I was certain I did. The job works, anyway :) Thanks!